# white-space:normal inside white-space:nowrap

Tags: html, css

I want to put a list of SPAN with white-space:normal inside a span with white-space:nowrap.
when i try the code above in firefox works.
when i try in the chrome don't work.
how to fix it?

```
<div style="overflow: auto; width: 100%; white-space: nowrap;" class="well">

            <span style="margin: 10px; position: relative;">
                <img data-src="holder.js/150x150" class="img-rounded img-polaroid" alt="150x150" style="width: 150px; height: 150px;">
                <a href="/promo-web/promocao/13">
                    <span style="position: absolute; left: 5px;white-space:normal">alienígenas de são cristovão e o melhor do sorvete</span>
                </a>


            </span>

            <span style="margin: 10px; position: relative;">
                <img data-src="holder.js/150x150" class="img-rounded img-polaroid" alt="150x150" style="width: 150px; height: 150px;">
                <a href="/promo-web/promocao/13">
                    <span style="position: absolute; left: 5px;white-space:normal">alienígenas de são cristovão e o melhor do sorvete</span>
                </a>


            </span>

            <span style="margin: 10px; position: relative;">
                <img data-src="holder.js/150x150" class="img-rounded img-polaroid" alt="150x150" style="width: 150px; height: 150px;">
                <a href="/promo-web/promocao/13">
                    <span style="position: absolute; left: 5px;white-space:normal">alienígenas de são cristovão e o melhor do sorvete</span>
                </a>


            </span>
...
```

Comment: 1. You shouldn't use inline styles. Use CSS. 2. How is it `not working` in Chrome? 3. Please upload your relevant code to http://www.jsfiddle.net and give us the link so we can look at it.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing some concepts about html & css.

- Separe css from html.
- For containers, use `div`. Use `span` just to style inline elements.
- Don't abuse on creating to many DOM elements.

See my solution (instead of `div` you can use `ul` & `li` too).
Also, if possible, show the image as `a` background-image instead creating a `img` tag and applying absolute positioning.

http://jsfiddle.net/jvHZq/

HTML:

```
<div class="well">
    <div>
        <img data-src="holder.js/150x150" class="img-rounded img-polaroid" />
        <a href="/promo-web/promocao/13">alienígenas de são cristovão e o melhor do sorvete</a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <img data-src="holder.js/150x150" class="img-rounded img-polaroid" />
        <a href="/promo-web/promocao/13">alienígenas de são cristovão e o melhor do sorvete</a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <img data-src="holder.js/150x150" class="img-rounded img-polaroid" />
        <a href="/promo-web/promocao/13">alienígenas de são cristovão e o melhor do sorvete</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.well {
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;   
}
.well > div {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    white-space:normal;
    width: 33%;
}
img {
    width: 150px; height: 150px;   
}
a {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 5px;
}
```